# Multiple status_code in Ansible uri module

Tags: ansible, uri

I am using ansible uri module to make a POST request. The request returns status either 201 or 208 and both status code should be considered for the task to pass. How can I specify multiple status_code value or how can I achieve this?

```
  - uri:
      url: "http://mywebsite.org/api/hooks/release/builtin/"
      method: POST
      HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
      body: '{"version": "6.2.10"}'
      body_format: json
      status_code: 208
    register: result
    failed_when: status_code != 201 or status_code != 208
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per [`uri` module manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html):

> `status_code` A valid, numeric, HTTP status code that signifies success of the request. **Can also be comma separated list of status codes**.

So:

```
- uri:
    url: "http://mywebsite.org/api/hooks/release/builtin/"
    method: POST
    HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
    body: '{"version": "6.2.10"}'
    body_format: json
    status_code: 201, 208
  register: result
```

Comment: tried doing that but it says status_code not defined

Comment: You should get rid of that line altogether then. And that's why when asking on StackOverflow you should include a verifiable example with the error you get.

Comment: I think it's the `failed_when` that is failing, but yeah, @drishtiahuja needs to communicate the problem better.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that you can also give the status codes in a more traditional ansible list format (one item per line):

```
- uri:
  url: "http://mywebsite.org/api/hooks/release/builtin/"
  method: POST
  HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
  body: '{"version": "6.2.10"}'
  body_format: json
  status_code:
    - 201
    - 208
    - 409
register: result
```

Answer (score 1):

**The solution using failed_when**

The `failed_when` needs to use `not in` and `result.status` to evaluate this correctly like this:

`failed_when: result.status not in [201,208]`

**Problem with the code in the question**
The first issue is that `status_code` cannot be referenced like this. However, you can reference `status` using the registered `result` object. So then the `failed_when` statemment would look like: 
`failed_when: result.status != 201 or result.status != 208`

However, this still fails when `201` or `208` are returned since if the `status` is `208` then it does not equal `201` and the `result.status != 201` conditional fails (and vice versa).

Comment: "status_code is an invalid attribute for the uri module" – how is that?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov thanks once I made a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example I realized I had status code attribute applied to the `task` level and not as a part of the attributes of the `uri` module. I have removed this incorrect information from my answer.

Comment: The important take away here is that `status_code` in uri module is a list. You need to check against a list also in the `when` condition.